# RewriteRule not working in .htaccess but without error

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I have a rewrite rule that it's not working but it doesn't throw any error so I can't figure it out. The `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteRule ^help/(.*)\.html$ /site/help.php?topic=$1 [L]
```

Also, in `httpd.conf` I have

```
<Directory "/Users/user/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Edit: I have XAMPP (1.7.3) on Mac OS 10.6.7

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the mod_rewrite module loaded in Apache?   I don't know XAMPP, so I can't tell you precisely where to look.

Comment: Yes, it is. I have other rules that are working (e.g. ErrorDocument).

Comment: ErrorDocument is not part of mod_rewrite so you cannot base your conclusion on that. Look in the configuration files, does it actually load mod_rewrite? Or create a php file containing <?php print_r(apache_get_modules()); ?> and open it in your browser. look for mod_rewrite, is it there?

Comment: Yes, it is. XAMPP comes with it by default, but I also checked as you suggested.